# Not generating report folder - Cucumber-JVM 6 Report generation using ExtentReports Adapter plugin

Tags: maven, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, extentreports

I am trying to generate report using Cucumber-JVM 6 Report generation using ExtentReports Adapter plugin using this ref - https://grasshopper.tech/2098/. But it is not generating any report folders and i am not sure what is the exact problem. Kindly help to resolve this issue.

pom.xml

```
    package runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features/",
        glue="testcases",tags="@RegTest",
        plugin= {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"})

public class TestRunner {

}
```

extent-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extentreports>
    <configuration>
        <!-- report theme -->

        <!-- standard, dark -->

        <theme>dark</theme>
        <!-- document encoding -->

        <!-- defaults to UTF-8 -->

        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <!-- protocol for script and stylesheets -->

        <!-- defaults to https -->

        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <!-- title of the document -->
        <documentTitle>Extent</documentTitle>
        <!-- report name - displayed at top-nav -->

        <reportName>Grasshopper Report</reportName>
        <!-- location of charts in the test view -->

        <!-- top, bottom -->

        <testViewChartLocation>bottom</testViewChartLocation>
        <!-- custom javascript -->

        <scripts>

            <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
});
]]>
        </scripts>
        <!-- custom styles -->
        <styles>
            <![CDATA[
]]>
        </styles>
    </configuration>
</extentreports>
```

extent.properties

```
extent.reporter.spark.start=true
extent.reporter.spark.out=test-output/SparkReport/Spark.html
extent.reporter.spark.config=src/test/resources/extent-config.xml

extent.reporter.spark.out=test-output/SparkReport/

screenshot.dir=test-output/
screenshot.rel.path=../
```